# Is there an equivalent to Debian's cli/php.ini on Redhat?

Tags: php5, rhel6, php.ini

How do you configure the command line version of PHP to have different settings on a Redhat system?

On Debian based systems, php has a separate command-line version config file: `/etc/php5/cli`.

On Redhat, there's `/etc/php.ini` and various additional ini files in `/etc/php.d/` but no separate config file for the command line version, even though the php-cli package is installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use the `-c` argument to indicate the ini file location
2. Create a `php-cli.ini` file on `/etc/`

[image]

From the [official PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php):

> The configuration file (php.ini) is read when PHP starts up. For the
>   server module versions of PHP, this happens only once when the web
>   server is started. For the CGI and CLI versions, it happens on every
>   invocation.
>
> **php.ini is searched for in these locations (in order):**
>
> - SAPI module specific location (PHPIniDir directive in Apache 2, **-c command line option in CGI and CLI**, php_ini parameter in NSAPI,
>     PHP_INI_PATH environment variable in THTTPD)
> - The PHPRC environment variable. Before PHP 5.2.0, this was checked after the registry key mentioned below.
> - As of PHP 5.2.0, the location of the php.ini file can be set for different versions of PHP. The following registry keys are examined in
>     order: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\x.y.z],
>     [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\x.y] and
>     [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\x], where x, y and z mean the PHP
>     major, minor and release versions. If there is a value for IniFilePath
>     in any of these keys, the first one found will be used as the location
>     of the php.ini (Windows only).
> - [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP], value of IniFilePath (Windows only).
> - Current working directory (except CLI).
> - The web server's directory (for SAPI modules), or directory of PHP (otherwise in Windows).
> - Windows directory (C:\windows or C:\winnt) (for Windows), or --with-config-file-path compile time option.
>
> **If php-SAPI.ini exists** (where SAPI is the SAPI in use, so, **for
>   example, php-cli.ini** or php-apache.ini), **it is used instead of
>   php.ini.** The SAPI name can be determined with php_sapi_name().